# Filter dataframe based on string within column

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

So for simplicity purposes since my data set is very large, let's say I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Foo', 'Foo1'], ['Bar', 'Bar2'], ['FooBar', 'FooBar3']],
columns= ['Col_A', 'Col_B'])
```

I need to filter this dataframe in a way that would eliminate an entire row when a specified column row contains a partial, non case sensitive string (foo). In this case, I tried this to no avail...PS, my regex skills are trash so forgive me if it's not working for that reason.

```
df = df[df['Col_A'] != '^[Ff][Oo][Oo].*']
```

Due to the size of my dataset, efficiency is a concern which is why I have not opted for the iteration route. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew the question that you marked as duplicate seems to concern filtering entire columns, rather than the content contained within the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.match`

```
df[~df['Col_A'].str.match('^[Ff][Oo][Oo].*')]
```

result

```
    Col_A   Col_B
1   Bar     Bar2
```

Comment: This solution is just what I needed and seems to be moldable for other situations I need to do this in. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Another method would be too use `str.startswith` with `str.lower` and the `NOT` operator `~`:

```
df[~df['Col_A'].str.lower().str.startswith('foo')]
```

**Output**

```
  Col_A Col_B
1   Bar  Bar2
```